# References for some analogs of the Picard group.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold. By definition,
$Pic(X)={\rm H^1}(X,\mathcal{O}^\times)$. We know a lot 
about this group. What is known about the groups
${\rm H^n}(X,\mathcal{O}^\times)$ for $n\ge 2$?

A bit more specialized question. It is well known that for a 
nonsingular projective complex variety $X$ the natural map 
$${\rm H^1}(X,\mathcal{O}^\times)\to{\rm H^1}(X,\mathcal{M}^\times)$$
is trivial. What is known about the kernel of the same map
for $n=2$ or $n=3$? (Here $\mathcal{M}^\times$ is the sheaf of 
nonzero meromorphic functions, and the topology is the strong one).

Comment: $H^2(X,\mathcal{O}^{\times})$ is often called the (cohomological) Brauer group. There is a vast literature on it.

Comment: Thank you. But I would like to have some examples at hand. And, what about $n=3$?

Comment: Indeen, after little googling I found some papers about this. 
Though, in the most of them the cohomology is etale.

Comment: And, apparently, all they care about is the torsion.

Comment: @Alex I am no expert, but I believe if you are looking at compact complex manifolds as you originally stated then $H^i(X,\mathcal{O}^{\times}) = H^i(X,\mathbb{G}_m)$,  since the complex topology is (morally) as good as the étale topology. However with arbitrary varieties it is better to work with $H_{ét}^i(X,\mathbb{G}_m)$ than $H^i(X,\mathcal{O}^{\times})$.

Comment: Also, at least if your variety is sufficiently nice over a field $K$, then $H_{ét}^2(X,\mathbb{G}_m)$ injects inside $H_{ét}^2(K,K(X)^{\times})$, where $K(X)$ is the field of rational functions. This is a galois cohomology group, so is therefore neccessarily torsion.

Comment: Sorry, that should be the Brauer group of the function field, not $H^2_{ét}(K,K(X)^{\times})$. For a field $L$ we define its Brauer group to be $H^2(L, L^{s\times})$.

Comment: Perhaps it is better (less hard) to work with etale topology,
but I am interested in transcendental methods. I think you are right that the etale cohomology is torsion, but the Cech one certainly is not.

Comment: The following link might help. I like it because it's a pretty categorical approach and that appeals to me. But it's also full of links to other sources which don't take that same approach:      http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/string/archives/000786.html

Comment: Thank you. This is not bad, though a bit too categorical to my taste. I am not satisfied with this (and other) sources for two reasons: 1) They ignore the nontorsion part in $H^2(X,\mathcal{O}^{\times})$. 2) They never go further, to $H^3(X,\mathcal{O}^{\times})$. I have some suspicion that for $H^3$ the things are completely different.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it probably depends on how you define $H^1(X, \mathcal{O}^\times)$. I don't see any reason why derived functor cohomology should agree here with Cech cohomology.

I think that $H^i(X, \mathcal{O}^\times)$ is a functor of order $i+1$ in the sense of Mumford "Abelian Varieties" (2.6, Remark preceding the proof of the theorem of the cube), at least for complex projective varieties. That is, there is a higher analogue of the theorem of the cube for $H^i(X, \mathcal{O}^\times)$. For this, we look at the exponential sequence as in the aforementioned Remark.

Comment: To clarify the question: $H^n$ there is the Cech cohomology 
group (in the strong topology). Thank you for the idea, but 
if there exists an analog of the theorem of the cube, I would prefer to read about it. To get it for myself may be not so easy. 

Comment: By a theorem of Godemont, on a Hausdorff paracompact space, Cech and derived cohomology always coincide. Assuming that "strong topology" is the analytic topology, that means you don't have to worry about this issue. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19312/example-wanted-when-does-cech-cohomology-fail-to-be-the-same-as-derived-functor/19723#19723 for further discussion.

Comment: Yes, I meant the analytic topology, of course. Actually, I was pretty sure that these cohomology coincide, though did not know where to look for this. Thanks. But, what I am looking for are not some functorial properties but nontrivial results PUBLISHED somewhere. To read it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reference: Grothendieck's [three exposés](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=244269) in *Dix Exposés sur la Cohomologie des Schémas* (and the references therein). One can find there e.g. computation of $H^i_{ét}({\rm Spec}\text{ } \mathcal{O}_K, \mathbb{G}_m)$ for spectra of rings of integers in number fields.

MR0244269 (39 #5586a) Grothendieck, Alexander Le groupe de Brauer. I. Algèbres d'Azumaya et interprétations diverses. (French) 1968 Dix Exposés sur la Cohomologie des Schémas pp. 46–66 North-Holland, Amsterdam; Masson, Paris, 14.55

MR0244270 (39 #5586b) Grothendieck, Alexander Le groupe de Brauer. II. Théorie cohomologique. (French) 1968 Dix Exposés sur la Cohomologie des Schémas pp. 67–87 North-Holland, Amsterdam; Masson, Paris, 14.55

MR0244271 (39 #5586c) Grothendieck, Alexander Le groupe de Brauer. III. Exemples et compléments. (French) 1968 Dix Exposés sur la Cohomologie des Schémas pp. 88–188 North-Holland, Amsterdam; Masson, Paris (Reviewer: J. S. Milne), 14.55