# An example where Čech and derived functor cohomologies don't agree.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cech-cohomology, derived-functors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Example Wanted: When Does Cech Cohomology Fail to be the same as Derived Functor Cohomology?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19312/example-wanted-when-does-cech-cohomology-fail-to-be-the-same-as-derived-functor)

Is there a simple example of a topological space $X$ with a sheaf $\mathcal F$ such that Čech and derived functor cohomologies don't agree? (I don't have any knowledge of schemes, I want $X$ to be a topological space)

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19312/example-wanted-when-does-cech-cohomology-fail-to-be-the-same-as-derived-functor